# TSQL - Bringing Data Together from Different Sources ...refactoring PK and FKs

Tags: stored-procedures, t-sql

I have various offices and one central head office. Each office has its own SQL Server instance so each office has its own data set with its own set of IDs.

Each office has already imported data into the head office and stored the data on a set of `STAGING_Tables` that look like this.

```
DECLARE @STAGING_COUNTRY TABLE
(
  Original_CountryID INT NOT NULL, 
  OfficeID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  Data VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @STAGING_CITY TABLE
(
  Original_CityID INT NOT NULL, 
  Original_CountryID_FK INT NOT NULL, 
  OfficeID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  OtherData VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

`STAGING_COUNTRY` has the original ID of each row (which off course will be duplicated since each office will have `ID=1` for the 1st row on their `Country` table) and also has a unique `OfficeID` value that together with the `Original_CountryID` ..makes a unique value.

`STAGING_CITY` has also the original `ID` of each row, the unique `OfficeID` value that represent each office and in this case a FK to `CountryID`, (but of course at this point we have a reference to the `Original_CountryID` ..that in conjunction with the office `ID` could be identified).

Let's add some dummy rows:

```
/* ADD DUMMY VALUES TO STAGING_COUNTRY */ 
INSERT INTO @STAGING_COUNTRY
(Original_CountryID, OfficeID, Data) VALUES  (1, 'Office1', 'USA')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_COUNTRY (Original_CountryID, OfficeID, Data)
VALUES  (2, 'Office1', 'Canada')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_COUNTRY (Original_CountryID, OfficeID, Data)
VALUES  (3, 'Office1', 'Japan')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_COUNTRY (Original_CountryID, OfficeID, Data)
VALUES  (1, 'Office2', 'USA')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_COUNTRY (Original_CountryID, OfficeID, Data)
VALUES  (1, 'Office2', 'Italy')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_COUNTRY (Original_CountryID, OfficeID, Data)
VALUES  (3, 'Office2', 'Canada')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_COUNTRY (Original_CountryID, OfficeID, Data)
VALUES  (3, 'Office3', 'Canada')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_COUNTRY (Original_CountryID, OfficeID, Data)
VALUES  (2, 'Office3', 'France')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_COUNTRY (Original_CountryID, OfficeID, Data)
VALUES  (3, 'Office3', 'USA')



/* ADD DUMMY VALUES TO STAGING_CITY */  
INSERT INTO @STAGING_CITY (Original_CityID, Original_CountryID_FK, OfficeID, OtherData) VALUES 
(1, 1, 'Office1', 'New York')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_CITY (Original_CityID, Original_CountryID_FK,
OfficeID, OtherData) VALUES  (2, 1, 'Office1', 'Vancouver')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_CITY (Original_CityID, Original_CountryID_FK,
OfficeID, OtherData) VALUES  (3, 1, 'Office1', 'Tokia')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_CITY (Original_CityID, Original_CountryID_FK,
OfficeID, OtherData) VALUES  (1, 2, 'Office2', 'New York')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_CITY (Original_CityID, Original_CountryID_FK,
OfficeID, OtherData) VALUES  (2, 2, 'Office2', 'Rome')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_CITY (Original_CityID, Original_CountryID_FK,
OfficeID, OtherData) VALUES  (3, 2, 'Office2', 'Vancouver')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_CITY (Original_CityID, Original_CountryID_FK,
OfficeID, OtherData) VALUES  (1, 3, 'Office3', 'Vancouver')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_CITY (Original_CityID, Original_CountryID_FK,
OfficeID, OtherData) VALUES  (2, 3, 'Office3', 'Paris')

INSERT INTO @STAGING_CITY (Original_CityID, Original_CountryID_FK,
OfficeID, OtherData) VALUES  (3, 3, 'Office3', 'New York')
```

The central head office wants to run reports from  a central dtabase that pretty much contains copy all the data from all offices but in order to make this reporting DB optimized, we need to reshuffle a bit the `STAGING_Tables` ...and reorganize the data in `FINAL_Tables` that look like this:

```
DECLARE @FINAL_COUNTRY TABLE
(
  CountryID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
  Original_CountryID INT NOT NULL, 
  OfficeID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  Data VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @FINAL_CITY TABLE
(
  CityID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
  Original_CityID INT NOT NULL, 
  CountryID_FK INT NOT NULL, 
  OfficeID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  OtherData VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

**PROBLEM:**
The `FINAL_COUNTRY` and `FINAL_CITY` tables should be as optimized as possible for reporting purposes. These reports will be written in T-SQL stored procedures.

**QUESTION:**
What is the best way to reorganize the `FINAL_Tables` so that each record has a TRUE PK identifier (like in the original `Office_Tables`) and each FK is updated to point to the right newly created PK ...at the server level?

**NOTE:**
Please note that both staging & final tables are inside the same DB, on the server.
Also we still need to keep the `OriginalID`s on the `FINAL_Tables` for other purposes.

**GOALS:**
The main goal here is to reorganize into a set of tables that can be easily indexed for performance purposes.

Please ask more info if needed.

Many many thanks in advanced...

Comment: Congratulations, you can now add "data warehouse" to your résumé!

Answer (score 1):

The `IDENTITY` key in your `FINAL_COUNTRIES` table is just fine for a PK.  You've created a "synthetic key."  I would also add a UQ on { OriginalCountryID, OfficeID }, to speed joins from staged data.

Another option would be to have a `Countries` table in your warehouse with only unique values (e.g., "USA" just once) and then a `CountriesMap` table relating OfficeID and CountryID to the ID in the warehouse table.  This would help performance, as when you get to your fact tables you'll want to use a single `INT` to relate to the Countries table, rather than an `INT` and a `VARCHAR()` - fact tables can get big fast, and it's important to keep them as narrow as you can.